# Batch remove substring from filename with special characters in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, filenames, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have a list of files in my directory:

```
opencv_calib3d.so2410.so
opencv_contrib.so2410.so
opencv_core.so2410.so
opencv_features2d.so2410.so
opencv_flann.so2410.so
opencv_highgui.so2410.so
opencv_imgproc.so2410.so
opencv_legacy.so2410.so
opencv_ml.so2410.so
opencv_objdetect.so2410.so
opencv_ocl.so2410.so
opencv_photo.so2410.so
```

They're the product of a series of mistakes made with batch renames, and now I can't figure out how to remove the middle ".so" from each of them.  For example:

`opencv_ocl.so2410.so` should be `opencv_ocl2410.so`

This is what I've tried:

```
# attempt 1, replace the (first) occurrence of `.so` from the filename
for f in opencv_*; do mv "$f" "${f#.so}"; done

# attempt 2, escape the dot
for f in opencv_*; do mv "$f" "${f#\.so}"; done

# attempt 3, try to make the substring a string
for f in opencv_*; do mv "$f" "${f#'.so'}"; done

# attempt 4, combine 2 and 3
for f in opencv_*; do mv "$f" "${f#'\.so'}"; done
```

But *all* of those have no effect, producing the error messages:

```
mv: ‘opencv_calib3d.so2410.so’ and ‘opencv_calib3d.so2410.so’ are the same file
mv: ‘opencv_contrib.so2410.so’ and ‘opencv_contrib.so2410.so’ are the same file
mv: ‘opencv_core.so2410.so’ and ‘opencv_core.so2410.so’ are the same file
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in your `mv` command:

```
mv "$f" "${f/.so/}"
```

First match of `.so` is being replaced by empty string.

Comment: Great. Much simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
a='opencv_calib3d.so2410.so'
echo "${a%%.so*}${a#*.so}"
opencv_calib3d2410.so
```

Where:

- `${a%%.so*}` - the part *before* the first `.so`
- `${a#*.so}` - the part *after* the first `.so`

Comment: @kdbanman if your question is answered, you should mark it as such.