# How to rename folders that contain consistent sub-string at the end using mv command?

Tags: macos, unix, mv

I have many folders with the following pattern:

```
$ ls
a-master 123-master abc123-master
```

I want them to be:

```
$ ls
a 123 abc123
```

During my research, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253047/1577357). But when I ran `mv "$f" "${f/-master/}"`, I got `mv: rename  to : No such file or directory` error and I'm not sure why.

I found many answers recommending *rename* package but I don't prefer it. I think it's possible to be done just by using *mv* command but I'm not entirely sure how.

Does is possible? If possible, what is the correct command for this case?

I'm looking for one liner command, a short and sweet one.

Answer (score 0):

I am fetching details from the shared link-

for **f** in opencv_*; do mv "$f" "${f/.so/}"; done

The mv command is working on a loop where f is defined as a temporary variable, whereas the query posted does not have a variable. (f == "")

Example,
mkdir abc123-master
export F=abc123-master
mv $F ${F/-master/}
ls -rlt
abc123